# Rendering a list as a 2-column html table in a django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an ordered list that I'm rendering as a 2-column html table in a Django template. In the table, the elements should be output so that the first (n+1)/2 elements are in the first column and the remainder are in the second column, as follows:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Elem 1</td>
     <td>Elem 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Elem 2</td>
    <td>Elem 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Elem 3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Assuming that my elements are in the context as `{{ elems }}`, how could I reasonably accomplish this in a Django template?

Comment: I think you will have to format/rearrange your `elems` in the view so that it can be used that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check [this recipe](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/401/). You might have to modify it, but you will get the idea.

Using it, in your template you would just do:

```
{% for row in elems|columns:2 %}
 <tr>
    {% for item in row %}
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I modified this snippet to display the items in order (from left to right): just change the `return` expression by this one: `return [thelist[n*i:n*(i+1)] for i in range(split)]`